# Sorting event not working on grid which raised event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a multiple kendo MVC grids with a sort event so that if a sort is applied on one grid it is also applied to all other grids. This seemed to work fine until I needed to override the sort function and sort on 2 columns.

The code below will now sort all other grids by 2 columns but not the grid that raised the event when the column was clicked to sort.

Is there a way to fix this so that the grid which is clicked also sorts correctly?

Razer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grids.Count; i++)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(dataXYZ)
          .Name($"grid{i}")
          .Deferred()
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              // Columns

          })
          .Sortable(sortable =>
          {
              sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
          })
          .Events(events => events
              .Sort("onSorting")
              .DataBound("dataBound")
          )
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(50)
              .ServerOperation(false)
          )

   ) 
}
```

javascript:

```
<script>


    function onSorting(arg) {
        $("div[data-role=grid]").each(function () {
            var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");

            var dsSort = [];
            dsSort.push({ field: "SortColumnHelper", dir: "desc" });
            dsSort.push({ field: arg.sort.field, dir: arg.sort.dir });

            grid.dataSource.sort(dsSort);

        });
    }


</script>
```

Edit: I think what's happening is that the sort event is called before the grid is sorted, so the code works but then the real sort takes place after the event code has run.

Comment: Can't you add your sort event to the DataSource rather Grid? Haven't checked but it will definitely solve your problem if it allows you to

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure a way to do this, the dataBound event fires after a sort so each grid can also be looped again and capture the unsorted grid.

```
<script>

    function onSorting(arg) {
        $("div[data-role=grid]").each(function () {
            var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");

            grid.dataSource.sort({});
            var dsSort = [];
            dsSort.push({ field: "SortColumnHelper", dir: "desc" });
            dsSort.push({ field: arg.sort.field, dir: arg.sort.dir });
            grid.dataSource.sort(dsSort);


        });
    }

    function dataBound(arg) {

        $("div[data-role=grid]").each(function (e) {
            var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
            var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();

            var sort = grid.dataSource.sort();
            if (sort != null && sort.length > 0 && sort.length <= 1) {

                var sortedField = sort[0].field;
                var sortedDir = sort[0].dir;
                if (sortedField != "SortColumnHelper") {

                    //console.log(this.id + " " + sortedField + " " + sortedDir);
                    var dsSort = [];
                    dsSort.push({ field: "SortColumnHelper", dir: "desc" });
                    dsSort.push({ field: sortedField, dir: sortedDir });
                    grid.dataSource.sort(dsSort);
                }
            }

        });
    }

</script>
```

The key thing here is that the sort length should be checked for an upper limit otherwise the sorting will retrigger the dataBound event and then resort etc, which will create an overflow error.

`if (sort != null && sort.length > 0 && sort.length <= 1)`

Essentially this checks if a grid has been sorted on 1 column only and then apply a sort on 2 columns.

It seems a bit 'hacky' but can;t find another way to do this on the MVC kendo docs